# Python syxtax error

Tags: python, syntax-error, nonetype

Im trying to write this procedure that calculate the difference in days between two dates, counting leap days and the 2nd input date is always after the 1st

Update: no more NoneType error, but it says syntax error at def test():
that line def test() (and those following) was written by the question giver (Udacity.com) what's the syntax error there?

```
def order4(y,m,d): #refers to the order of the date counting from the last leap year
    mo=0
    for i in range(m-1):
        if i in set([0,2,4,6,7,9,11]):
            mo=mo+31
        if i == 1:
            mo=mo+28
        if i in set([3,5,8,10]):
            mo = mo+30
# mo = number of days from the beginning of the year to the current month
    order = 365*(y%4)+mo+d
    if order > 59 and (y%4,m,d)!=(0,2,29):
        order = order+1
    return int(order) 

print(order4(2011,6,30)) #to check that they are correct output numbers
print(order4(2012,6,30)) #to check that they are correct output numbers

def daysBetweenDates(year1,month1,day1,year2,month2,day2):
    diffdate = order4(year2,month2,day2)-order4(year1,month1,day1)
    if diffdate<0:
        diffdate=diffdate+1461
    return int((year2-year1)/4)+diffdate

print(daysBetweenDates(2012,1,1,2012,2,28))

def test():
    test_cases = [((2012,1,1,2012,2,28), 58), 
                  ((2012,1,1,2012,3,1), 60),
                  ((2011,6,30,2012,6,30), 366),
                  ((2011,1,1,2012,8,8), 585 ),
                  ((1900,1,1,1999,12,31), 36523)]
    for (args, answer) in test_cases:
        result = daysBetweenDates(*args)
        if result != answer:
            print ("Test with data:", args, "failed")
        else:
            print ("Test case passed!")
```

Comment: Your code is hard to read. Please use valid names and follow a naming convention to make it readable.

Comment: any library imports in the beginning? what string is actual #19 in your code?

Comment: As far as I see there is no error in line 19. But I see error in variabeles at line 22. with global variables year2 and year1

Comment: Please post your entire script, the error is not in the snippet you have posted.

Comment: the error is actually in there, I just fixxed the previous error but now another appears

Comment: @UmaKanth Im actually teaching myself so Im not even sure there's a convention. Where can I read about it please?

Comment: @VũKarobettaTrọngNghĩa Good that you want to learn. Here's a [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29).

Comment: Can you please paste the complete traceback?

Comment: add `print y,m,d,ye,mo,da` in line 19 and have a look at the values those params have

Answer (score 1):

I cut and pasted your code into a local file, ran it in both Python3 and Python2 and received no syntax errors and both produced the output:

```
1277
182
58
```

Remember that Python differentiates between tabs and spaces, even though they both look the same.   It sounds like it is possible that your file contains incorrect indentation because there are tabs in your file?

As a suggestion, I recommend you use an editor, such as Emacs or SublimeText, which has a Python mode and can help you make sure the source code is correctly formatted.